# Unable to access XML file from NSCachesDirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, vuforia

I have a xml file in **`NSCachesDirectory`**, When I tried to access the file then getting nil value while same file if i want to access from NSBundle then it is working. Below the screenshot and code snippet-

```
 // load the data associated to the trackers
- (bool) doLoadTrackersData {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cacheDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *bookCode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"bookCode"];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:cacheDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@%s",bookCode,bookCode,bookCode,".xml"]];
    NSLog(@"The path for xml ImageTarget is  = %@",url.absoluteString);
    dataSetStonesAndChips = [self loadObjectTrackerDataSet:url.absoluteString];
    dataSetTarmac = [self loadObjectTrackerDataSet:@"Tarmac.xml"];
    if ((dataSetStonesAndChips == NULL) || (dataSetTarmac == NULL)) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load datasets");
        return false;
    }
    if (! [self activateDataSet:dataSetStonesAndChips]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to activate dataset");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**`The path for xml ImageTarget is  = file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/55240D59-8811-4A35-867F-D648197FB611/Library/Caches/AHW2/AHW2/AHW2.xml`**

[image]

Code for locally access xml file and it's working -

```
// load the data associated to the trackers
- (bool) doLoadTrackersData {
    dataSetStonesAndChips = [self loadObjectTrackerDataSet:@"AHW2.xml"];
    dataSetTarmac = [self loadObjectTrackerDataSet:@"Tarmac.xml"];
    if ((dataSetStonesAndChips == NULL) || (dataSetTarmac == NULL)) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load datasets");
        return false;
    }
    if (! [self activateDataSet:dataSetStonesAndChips]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to activate dataset");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Method for **`loadObjectTrackerDataSet`** -

```
// Load the image tracker data set
- (Vuforia::DataSet *)loadObjectTrackerDataSet:(NSString*)dataFile
{
    NSLog(@"loadObjectTrackerDataSet (%@)", dataFile);
    Vuforia::DataSet * dataSet = NULL;

    // Get the Vuforia tracker manager image tracker
    Vuforia::TrackerManager& trackerManager = Vuforia::TrackerManager::getInstance();
    Vuforia::ObjectTracker* objectTracker = static_cast<Vuforia::ObjectTracker*>(trackerManager.getTracker(Vuforia::ObjectTracker::getClassType()));

    if (NULL == objectTracker) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: failed to get the ObjectTracker from the tracker manager");
        return NULL;
    } else {
        dataSet = objectTracker->createDataSet();

        if (NULL != dataSet) {
            NSLog(@"INFO: successfully loaded data set");

            // Load the data set from the app's resources location
            if (!dataSet->load([dataFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], Vuforia::STORAGE_APPRESOURCE)) {
                NSLog(@"ERROR: failed to load data set");
                objectTracker->destroyDataSet(dataSet);
                dataSet = NULL;
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: failed to create data set");
        }
    }

    return dataSet;
}
```

Comment: What is a `loadObjectTrackerDataSet`? Maybe there is a problem?

Comment: If I tried with this, then its working,                                     
         dataSetStonesAndChips = [self loadObjectTrackerDataSet:@"AHW2.xml"];

Comment: so you may want to provide code to that function

Comment: I would like to see `loadObjectTrackerDataSet` it looks like you have this code duplicated there?

Comment: Again updated the working code. What i observed, the problem is only to acess the file from cache directory. loadObjectTrackerDataSet is fine. I tested it locally from NSBundle

Comment: Are you downloading this file from anywhere? or copying file from bundle to Cache directory?

Comment: I downloaded file AHW2.zip from server then unzip it. You can see it in attached screenshot

Comment: I am pretty sure, the main issue is -                                                                  
      NSURL *url = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:cacheDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@%s",bookCode,bookCode,bookCode,".xml"]];

Comment: So while unziping file it may possible your unzipped file may corrupt. Try to check the size of both files on your server and local cache directory. Maybe some file corrupt issue is there.

Comment: Dear, I copied the file to Bundle from unzip folder and it is working

Comment: As per @Lu comment Can you post your `loadObjectTrackerDataSet` method code so more light on how you are loading or reading XML file?

Comment: @CodeChanger actually it is a third party library name Vuforia, I am just using it. I think no need of this.. I already debugged

Comment: I don't think so as you are calling it with `Self` so it's written on your controller and maybe from that function you are calling Vuforia SDK method.

Comment: Updated the code for loadObjectTrackerDataSet, Please check

Comment: Just another hint: The caches directory gets randomly purged. Assuming documents to be there is not a good practice. Put your data in a folder in the documents directory and make it exempt from icloud.